# Direct user to different page based on network connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, webserver

I am currently working on upgrading an existing asp.net web application.  It is being hosted on our local web server and I would like to direct users to a different page if they are connecting locally.

Example: An employee connecting on our local network would be directed to page A.  If someone on an outside network connects (presumably a customer) they would be directed to page B.  Is this possible?  Does the web server know if the connection is local or not?  If so, I should be able to code for it.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had an embarrassingly **awful hack** in place for this kind of situation for years.  And while I'm sure there's a better way, what do do is look at the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` and if it matches a list we go to one page, otherwise we go another.

Comment: This certainly does the trick.  It may not be "proper" but hey, it works.  Thanks for the tip.